# Is there a way to send a static image that's a png in the body for a axios post in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, png

I'm looking to post a static default photo image in my asset folder to my endpoint if no image was uploaded to the input fileuploader. How do you send that through the body. I tried to send the import variable for it but upon getting the image it wasn't correct. Whats the correct way to go about this?

```
import DefaultPic from '../../../assets/avatars/default.png';

 axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_HOST + process.env.REACT_APP_PORT + '/users', 

             {
              firstName: this.state.firstName,
              lastName: this.state.lastName,
              image : DefaultPic
            }
          )
```

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is how to turn the import into a file object since if someone doesn't select an image how do I convert the file in my assets folder into what I will send. When I do type DefaultPic it's just a string.